# How can I delay the Trim Curve happen in different times for each curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this:

[image]

I would like to this but don't know how:

- Delay the curves to happen in different times per each curve from bottom to top
- To not have consistent amount of yellow dots per each curve, but increasing amount

The effect in [this video](https://youtu.be/pSFnkLGcOkw?t=53) in timestamp 0:53 is what I'm after.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there with the first problem. You just need to add a "Realize Instances" node before you do the trim curves. The curves then become objects that can then be manipulated individually. Or at least that's how I understand it!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Woah! Thank you! I never know when to actually use realize instances and when not, that's one bizarre node. But progress is made, thank you again! :)

Comment: Also, I tend to use "Frames" instead of "Seconds" for the input time node. Frames always references the frame itself, where Seconds can lead to unexpected results as it is dictated by the Project's Frame Rate setting. I just find it's easier to do the math in my head using frames!

Comment: @ManuJärvinen. I think of it like using the Array modifier (not in geo nodes). I can make an array with a ton of objects, but I can't change each object in that array separately, Change one and it changes all of them. If I "apply" the modifier, then each object can be edited separately. Instances are sorta like arrays, and realize instances is sorta like applying the array modifier so you can edit each object. That might not be totally accurate, and hope someone corrects me if not, but hope it helps.

Comment: but it is difficult to realize that you're editing those instances now individually - I mean, when you realize instances, you start to transform the whole block of instances easily all at the same time with pivot for all of them in one place somewhere - phew

Comment: @ManuJärvinen Try utilizing the viewer node and the spreadsheet view, incredibly useful information there. Hook up the geometry noodle before and after the realize instances node. Note on the left side panel in spreadsheet view how you have access to all the control points in each curve after "Realize Instances" but not if you hook it up before that node.

Comment: Oooh, thank you! I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

My second problem got solved by replacing the 'Curve to Points' node with 'Resample Curve' and using 'Length' for it, great!

But the 1st question is the main, harder one to tackle :/

Answer (score 0):

This was also a very good solution from a friend:

[image]